# How to reach formRegion_FormRegionInitializing runtime?

Tags: outlook-addin

Hello I'm trying to show/hide formRegion in outlook 2007 at Runtime. I have it showing/hiding with e.Cancel in FormRegionFactory_FormRegionInitializing, but it only refreshes when users selects another email. How do i reach event at runtime or there is a better way of showing/hiding the region in 2007 outlook.

```
if (Settings.Default.DisplayWhere == "WebBrowser")
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
else if(Settings.Default.DisplayWhere == "Outlook")
{
    e.Cancel = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the FormRegionInitializing event for hiding the form region at runtime. See [How to: Prevent Outlook from Displaying a Form Region](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608610.aspx) for more information.

Also you can set the [Visible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863603(v=office.15).aspx) property of the FormRegion class:

```
 WindowFormRegionCollection formRegions = 
    Globals.FormRegions
        [Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector()];
formRegions.FormRegion1.Visible = false;
```

See [Accessing a Form Region at Run Time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772084.aspx) for more information.

You may find the [Creating Outlook Form Regions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386301.aspx) section in MSDN helpful.